# How to fix the dependencies of a Maven JavaFX project ? (VsCode)

Tags: json, maven, visual-studio-code, javafx

I have tried several ways to make the UI of a board game and JavaFX seems to be easiest option. So I created a new Java project using Maven in VsCode with a JavaFX archetype. But now that I copied my java files and Maven dependencies, it seems that there are conflicts with some libraries. I get errors like :

- "The package javax.swing is not accessibleJava(268436910)", or
- "The type com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper is not accessibleJava(16778666)"

---

Here is my pom.xml :

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.monopoly</groupId>
    <artifactId>monopoly</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>11</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>11</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-controls</artifactId>
            <version>19</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-fxml</artifactId>
            <version>19</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>2.11.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>2.11.3</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <release>11</release>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
                <artifactId>javafx-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.0.8</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <!-- Default configuration for running -->
                        <!-- Usage: mvn clean javafx:run -->
                        <id>default-cli</id>
                        <configuration>
                            <mainClass>com.monopoly.App</mainClass>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

---

I haven't modified my files to use javafx yet, so some libraries will be replaced, but others won't, such as Json libraries. In any case, I hope it can help someone in the same situation.

I looked for version conflicts, but mvn dependency:tree is successful :

```
[INFO] -----------------------< com.monopoly:monopoly >------------------------
[INFO] Building monopoly 1.0
[INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:2.8:tree (default-cli) @ monopoly ---
[INFO] com.monopoly:monopoly:jar:1.0
[INFO] +- org.openjfx:javafx-controls:jar:19:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.openjfx:javafx-controls:jar:win:19:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.openjfx:javafx-graphics:jar:19:compile
[INFO] |     +- org.openjfx:javafx-graphics:jar:win:19:compile
[INFO] |     \- org.openjfx:javafx-base:jar:19:compile
[INFO] |        \- org.openjfx:javafx-base:jar:win:19:compile
[INFO] +- org.openjfx:javafx-fxml:jar:19:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.openjfx:javafx-fxml:jar:win:19:compile
[INFO] +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:jar:2.11.3:compile
[INFO] |  \- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:jar:2.11.3:compile
[INFO] \- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:jar:2.11.3:compile
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I also looked for answers on the net but that's a very specific topic, so haven't found anything yet. That's why I'm asking you guys. I'm not very experienced so I hope I gave enough information

Comment: Just paste the dependency tree into the question formatted as code, rather than as an image.

Comment: Do you have a `module-info.java`?  I guess so.  If you do, edit the question to add it, formatted as code.  Either you can delete it and make your app non-modular, or, if you want to keep a modular app, you can add the required modules to the `module-info.java`.  See [understanding modules](https://www.oracle.com/corporate/features/understanding-java-9-modules.html).

Comment: I don't advise mixing JavaFX and Swing unless you really need to.

Comment: Ensure you can get the JavaFX hello world in VSCode app from the getting started documentation at openjfx.io working in your environment.

Comment: @jewelsea thanks for the advice. I'll look more into the modules, I think it should be it. As for Swing, I think it will disappear when I update my files for JavaFX. I tested the base project of my archetype, which switches between 2 scenes, and it worked, so nothing wrong there.

Comment: For the code formatting, all you need to do is indent four spaces.  Don't mark the code as html/javascript if it isn't that or StackOverflow does weird things with the formatting.  See [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/75316446/revisions) for an example.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry if I'm late to answer, I forgot to post this. I found the answer with the help of @jewelsea. I was missing these lines in my module-info.java :

```
requires com.fasterxml.jackson.databind;
opens com.monopoly to javafx.fxml, com.fasterxml.jackson.databind;
```